# vscode change the icon color of the selected suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable / change the icon color of the selected suggestion to the default color

here's the current suggestion window foreground icon color, it turned to white when I focus on the suggestion

[image]

what I want is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I think you are asking how to change ONLY the icon color in a suggestion.]

Probably the same issue as [autocomplete suggestions icon and text colour got changed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125998)
.

Resolved in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/126288 by adding a new `colorCustomization` setting:

`list.activeSelectionIconForeground`

It is working in my Insiders Build now so should be in v1.58.

Comment: thanks, i thought its only on my machine 
appreciate it